# Cognito: re-send confirmation email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a scenario when the user never got (or lost) the registration email with the temporary password. Now common sense will drive the user to the "forgot password" process. But here, he'll get an error saying "User password cannot be reset in the current state." What now? I'm trying to find a way to re-send the email with the temporary password FROM the client-side.

I know there's the option of AdminCreateUser with "MessageAction": "RESEND" but that involves the back-end and I would prefer keeping this logic in a component in client-side (where the rest of the authentication logic already is).

I've been trying with the method "resendConfirmationCode" of CognitoUser but I get a "NotAuthorizedException" error with the message "Can't resend confirmation code for this user"

Every other post I've read regarding this very scenario ultimately proposes the AdminCreateUser option without even trying to explain why "resendConfirmationCode" doesn't work.

Even if it can't be done, any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the "confirmation" email wherein the activation code lies to confirm the email address and activate the account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't resend verification code through AWS Cognito API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194794/cant-resend-verification-code-through-aws-cognito-api)